# How can I add hyperlink to an HTML email|twitter|linkedin body?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, linkedin-api

I have a small website with 3 sharing buttons (Email, Linkedin, twitter).

I am trying to share a link that looks rather bad:

> [http://mywebsite.com/index?Summary=Churchill%20succeeded%20as%20an%20orator%20despite%20being%20handicapped%20from%20childhood%20with%20a%20speech%20impediment.%20He%20had%20a%20lateral%20lisp%20and%20was%20unable%20to%20pronounce%20the%20letter%20s%2C%20verbalising%20it%20with%20a%20slur.%20His%20first%20speech%20as%20prime%20minister%2C%20delivered%20to%20the%20commons%20on%2013%20may%20was%20the%20%22blood%2C%20toil%2C%20tears%20and%20sweat%22%20speech.%20His%20use%20of%20rhetoric%20hardened%20public%20opinion%20against%20a%20peaceful%20resolution%20and%20prepared%20the%20british%20people%20for%20a%20long%20war.%20He%20drafted%20outside%20experts%20into%20government%20to%20fulfil%20vital%20functions%2C%20especially%20on%20the%20home%20front.%20He%20believed%20that%20the%20only%20option%20was%20to%20fight%20on%2C%20even%20if%20france%20capitulated%2C%20but%20his%20position%20remained%20precarious%20until%20chamberlain%20resolved%20to%20support%20him.%20The%20war%20ended%20on%204%20June%201941%2C%20with%20the%20evacuation%20of%20dunkirk%20from%20allied%20servicemen%2C%20and%20the%20battle%20of%20france%20from%20france%20ended%20on%20tune%20on%204%20February%201942.%20He%20died%20of%20a%20heart%20attack%20in%20December%201941%2C%20at%20the%20age%20of%2048.%20He%20was%20succeeded%20by%20his%20son%2C%20the%20future%20prime%20minister%20of%20the%20UK%2C%20Edward%26nbsp%3BChurchill%2C%20who%20was%20also%20a%20war%20cabinet%20member.%20His%20funeral%20was%20held%20at%20St%20Paul's%20Cathedral%2C%20London%2C%20on%2011%20December%201941.%20He%20is%20buried%20in%20a%20plot%20of%20land%20he%20inherited%20from%20his%20father%2C%20which%20he%20had%20inherited%20when%20he%20became%20prime%20minister%20in%201940.%20He%20also%20had%20a%20house%20of%20honour%20at%20St%20James'%20Palace%2C%20London.%20His%20son%2C%20Edward%2C%20later%20became%20the%20Prime%20Minister%20of%20the%20United%20Kingdom.%20](http://mywebsite.com/index?Summary=Churchill%20succeeded%20as%20an%20orator%20despite%20being%20handicapped%20from%20childhood%20with%20a%20speech%20impediment.%20He%20had%20a%20lateral%20lisp%20and%20was%20unable%20to%20pronounce%20the%20letter%20s%2C%20verbalising%20it%20with%20a%20slur.%20His%20first%20speech%20as%20prime%20minister%2C%20delivered%20to%20the%20commons%20on%2013%20may%20was%20the%20%22blood%2C%20toil%2C%20tears%20and%20sweat%22%20speech.%20His%20use%20of%20rhetoric%20hardened%20public%20opinion%20against%20a%20peaceful%20resolution%20and%20prepared%20the%20british%20people%20for%20a%20long%20war.%20He%20drafted%20outside%20experts%20into%20government%20to%20fulfil%20vital%20functions%2C%20especially%20on%20the%20home%20front.%20He%20believed%20that%20the%20only%20option%20was%20to%20fight%20on%2C%20even%20if%20france%20capitulated%2C%20but%20his%20position%20remained%20precarious%20until%20chamberlain%20resolved%20to%20support%20him.%20The%20war%20ended%20on%204%20June%201941%2C%20with%20the%20evacuation%20of%20dunkirk%20from%20allied%20servicemen%2C%20and%20the%20battle%20of%20france%20from%20france%20ended%20on%20tune%20on%204%20February%201942.%20He%20died%20of%20a%20heart%20attack%20in%20December%201941%2C%20at%20the%20age%20of%2048.%20He%20was%20succeeded%20by%20his%20son%2C%20the%20future%20prime%20minister%20of%20the%20UK%2C%20Edward%26nbsp%3BChurchill%2C%20who%20was%20also%20a%20war%20cabinet%20member.%20His%20funeral%20was%20held%20at%20St%20Paul%27s%20Cathedral%2C%20London%2C%20on%2011%20December%201941.%20He%20is%20buried%20in%20a%20plot%20of%20land%20he%20inherited%20from%20his%20father%2C%20which%20he%20had%20inherited%20when%20he%20became%20prime%20minister%20in%201940.%20He%20also%20had%20a%20house%20of%20honour%20at%20St%20James%27%20Palace%2C%20London.%20His%20son%2C%20Edward%2C%20later%20became%20the%20Prime%20Minister%20of%20the%20United%20Kingdom.%20)

this is what I use in my HTML:

> <a class="twitter" href="" < /a>
> <a class="email" href="" < /a>
> <a class="linkedin" href="" < /a>

hrefs:

- **email**:
  "mailto:?body=Check out this Article Summarization " + ugly_url + "&subject= Summarization Tool";
- **twitter**:"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + ugly_url
- **linkedin**:"https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=" +ugly_url + "&title=Temporary Title&source=Chillyfacts";

how can I convert the messy URL into a hyperlink?

[mylink](https://googe.com)

Comment: Might be typos, but you are not closing the opening `a` tags in that HTML code you posted. (i.e. `>` is missing 3 times)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to interface with websites by creating links with parameters built-in. The proper way would be to create an API that interfaces with those websites.

Websites usually have pages dedicated to showing you how to do that. You can usually find them by googling "websiteName API". Twitter's, for example, is [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs)